# INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY error

Tags: mysql

I have this query

```
INSERT INTO outlet_inventory (outletid, itemid, itemqty)
VALUES('$outletid', '$itemid', '$qty') 
WHERE outletid = '$outletid'
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE outlet_inventory.itemqty = outlet_inventory.itemqty + $qty
```

As far as I can see there are no errors in it but I get this error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE outletid = 5' at line 5
```

Any idea whats wrong?

---

#### Update

Updated my query...still getting the same error.

```
INSERT INTO outlet_inventory (outletid, itemid, itemqty)
VALUES('$outletid', '$itemid', '$qty') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE outlet_inventory.itemqty = outlet_inventory.itemqty + $qty
WHERE outletid = '$outletid'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
INSERT INTO outlet_inventory (outletid, itemid, itemqty)
VALUES('$outletid', '$itemid', $qty) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE itemqty = itemqty + $qty
```

**EDIT**

You don't need to and cannot put a `WHERE` clause into a `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement. See the docs here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

You only can put a `WHERE` into a normal `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: hi. I need the WHERE clause so I could update a specific outlet.

Comment: added my response to the answer

Comment: Thanks! It works, though I really dont get why having WHERE doesnt work

Answer (score 3):

You have a `WHERE` clause on your `INSERT`. This should be on the `UPDATE` instead.

```
INSERT INTO outlet_inventory (outletid, itemid, itemqty)
VALUES('$outletid', '$itemid', '$qty') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE outlet_inventory.itemqty = outlet_inventory.itemqty + $qty     
WHERE outletid = '$outletid'
```

Comment: hi. I tried your suggestion but it still gave me the error on a different line.

Answer (score 3):

`WHERE` is [not valid in an `INSERT` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html), neither does it make any sense.

I think you meant for it to be part of your `UPDATE` clause.

Comment: I tried that but it still gave me an error on the WHERE clause

Comment: @JohnSmith: Then this is not the query you're running. Are you substituting your `$qty` for something? What are you substituting it for? Show us what you're _actually_ giving to MySQL, not some template in another language.